# Caesar cipher Encryption and Decryption using python

Tags: python, encryption

Develop two functions to encrypt and decrypt a given text in Caesar cypher. Given a text to encrypt,
alphabetic characters are all shifted by one and spaces are removed. To decrypt the text, the opposite
process is followed but spaces are not recovered. Notice that 'z' turns to 'a'. And all encryption is done on small letters version of the message.

I cant seem to get the "spaces are removed" part

Here is my attempt:

```
import string

alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_lowercase

sentence = list(input('enter your text: \n').lower())

what_to_do = input(
    'enter encrypt to ENCRYPT, decrypt to DECRYPT, exit to EXIT the program \n').lower()

shift_number = int(input('enter your shift number from 1 to 25: \n'))

end_program = False

while not end_program:
    if what_to_do == 'encrypt':
        for i in range(len(sentence)):
            if sentence[i] == ' ':
                sentence[i] = ' '
            else:
                new_letter = alphabets.index(sentence[i]) + shift_number
                sentence[i] = alphabets[new_letter]
        print(''.join(map(str, sentence)))
        end_program = True
    elif what_to_do == 'decrypt':
        for i in range(len(sentence)):
            if sentence[i] == ' ':
                sentence[i] = ' '
            else:
                new_letter = alphabets.index(sentence[i]) - shift_number
                sentence[i] = alphabets[new_letter]
        print(''.join(map(str, sentence)))
        end_program = True
    else:
        decide = input(
            'invalid entry, try again Y for YES, N for NO: \n').lower()
        if decide == 'y':
            sentence = list(input('enter your text: \n').lower())
            what_to_do = input(
                'enter encrypt to ENCRYPT, decrypt to DECRYPT, exit to EXIT the program \n').lower()
            shift_number = int(input('enter your shift number from 1 to 25: \n'))
        else:
            end_program = True
```

Comment: As you become more comfortable with python you'll be able to write this with much less code *and* the intent will be clearer. For now, since you want to get rid of spaces just get rid of them by replacing each one with the empty string; `sentence = list(input('enter your text: \n').replace(' ', '').lower())`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you so much, sir!

Comment: I like the way you solved this using two concatenated alphabets, but I would very much urge you to also try it with one alphabet and a modulus operation. The idea of groups and such is very strong in cryptography - you may need it later on.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am sorry I don't understand how can I use a modulus operation with the alphabet I am still new to programming so I am really bad sorry

Comment: So you define a variable which indicates the size of the alphabet, for the ABC that would be `n=26`. Then you use [the modulus operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/) and `n` to calculate the index within the alphabet after shifting. So instead of an index in the range [0, 52) you'd get an index in the range [0, 26). Then you only need one alphabet.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oh, I understand now thank you very much, sir! I appreciate it